# Using TouchSwipe with $(this)

Tags: jquery, touchswipe

I'm trying to figure out how to use the touchSwipe plugin to make it affect only one element.

```
<div class="element">Content 1 <p class="hello">Hello</p></div>
<div class="element">Content 2 <p class="hello">Hello</p></div>
<div class="element">Content 3 <p class="hello">Hello</p></div>
```

My jQuery goes like this:

```
$('.element').each(function() {
$(this).swipe({
swipeLeft: function() { $(this).find('.hello').fadeOut(300) }
});
});
```

Problem is this doesn't work (actually, nothing happens, but swipeLeft is recognized).

The effect I want basically is that if I swipe left on the div that has content 1, only its "Hello" should fade out.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to get the contents of the element you want to check for:

```
            var strID = $(this).html().substr(0, 9);
```

Then apply the fadeOut if the contents match your specified criteria, something like:

```
            if (strHTML == "Content 1")
                $(this).find(".hello").fadeOut(300);
```

Assuming of course you know the contents of the target element, or there's some discernible pattern you can use.